# Asignación masiva de un arreglo laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en laravel, tengo un formulario y un boton para duplicar el formulario en caso que se desee agregar mas de una mercancia

```js
$('.clonar').click(function() {
  // Clona el .input-group
  var $clone = $('#formulario .row').last().clone();

  // Borra los valores de los inputs clonados
  $clone.find(':input').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is('date')) {
      this.value = {{ date('Y-m-d') }};
    } else {
      this.value = '';
    }
  });

  // Agrega lo clonado al final del #formulario
  $clone.appendTo('#formulario');
  //Eliminar
  $(".removerFila").on("click", function(){ 
    $(this).closest(".row").remove(); });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<form class="row gy-5 gx-3 align-items-center" id="formulario" action="{{route('admin.lubricante.store')}}" method="POST">
    <div class="container col-md-4">
        <button type="button" class="clonar btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Agregar Producto</button>
        
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button><br>
    </div>

<div class="container row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="form-label">Fecha</label>
            <input type="date" name="fecha[]" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="form-label">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre[]" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="form-label">Cantidad</label>
            <input type="number" name="cantidad[]" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="form-label">Costo</label>
            <input type="number" step="0.01" name="costo[]" class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><br>
            <button type="button" class="clonar btn btn-danger btn-sm removerFila">Remover</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

la cuestion es que al momento de guardar la informacion en la base de datos lo hago de la siguiente manera:

**Controlador**

```
    public function store(StoreLubricantes $request){
    foreach ($request->fecha as $i => $fecha) {
        $lubri = new Lubricantes();
        $lubri->fecha = $request->fecha[$i];
        $lubri->nombre = $request->nombre[$i];
        $lubri->cantidad = $request->cantidad[$i];
        $lubri->costo = $request->costo[$i];
        $lubri->save();
    }
    return redirect()->route('admin.lubricante.index');
}
```

y ahora investigando un poco descubrí que en vez de hacer de la manera anterior puedo usar asignación masiva pero al momento de guardar me salta el siguiente error:

```
public function store(StoreLubricantes $request){
        Lubricantes::create($request->validated());     
    return redirect()->route('admin.lubricante.index');
```

> TypeError
> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\contable\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 898

Nose como pasar correctamente los datos del arreglo al controlador y no tengo idea de que cambiar para que funcione

Comment: Que hay en `$request->validated()`?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Bueno esto es lo que trae si creo 1 campo adicional:  {"fecha":["2022-05-06","2022-05-06"],"nombre":["1","2"],"cantidad":["1","2"],"costo":["1","2"]}

Comment: Bueno, en ese caso vas a tener  que hacer el foreach. Creo que lo que buscas es algo como el método [insert](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#insert-statements) pero tendrás que mapear los datos para que te queden los datos de cada fila en su correspondiente índice del array. Sería mejor que el frontend ya los enviara ordenados

Answer (score 0):

En tu pregunta no mencionas si lo que quieres es crear varias instancias de un modelo o una única instancia. Imagino que como dices que el formulario tiene un botón de clonar es que estás permitiendo crear varias.

Para eso el método `create()` no te servirá, te pongo en contexto. Cuando estás llamando al método `create()` de un Modelo de laravel este, mediante método mágico `__call()`, crea una instancia de Eloquent\Builder y llama a su método `create()`. Si miras [la documentación de la api de este método](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_create) verás que crea y devuelve una única instancia.

El único método que conozco que te permitiría crear varias es el método `insert()`. Este método es accesible vía el modelo gracias a método mágico mencionado anteriormente que llama al `insert()` de Eloquent\Builder y este a su vez mediante `__call()` al método `insert()` de Query\Builder. [Según la documentación](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_insert) este te permite crear varios valores pero no te los devuele. En tu caso creo que la devolución de las instancias no es relevante puesto que directamente desvías al usuario al listado de Lubricantes.

Bien hasta aquí la teoría para llegar a insertar todos los valores de golpe minimizando el impacto espacial y computacional.

Ahora tocaría ver cómo pasarle el arreglo (array) al método `insert()` que necesita un array de arrays clave valor mientras que tu tienes un array clave valor donde el valor es un array.

Bien, creo que lo mejor sería hacerlo en la parte del front, aún que quedará un poco más extraño, no tener que procesarlo en el back para reordenarlo te vendrá bien si piensas tener una elevada cantidad de usuarios :D.

Para eso plantearía algo del estilo:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<form class="row gy-5 gx-3 align-items-center" id="formulario" action="{{route('admin.lubricante.store')}}" method="POST">
    <div class="container col-md-4">
        <button type="button" class="clonar btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Agregar Producto</button>
        
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button><br>
    </div>

<div class="container row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="form-label">Fecha</label>
            <input type="date" name="values[1][fecha]" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="form-label">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="values[1][fecha]" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="form-label">Cantidad</label>
            <input type="number" name="values[1][cantidad]" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="form-label">Costo</label>
            <input type="number" step="0.01" name="values[1][costo]" class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><br>
            <button type="button" class="clonar btn btn-danger btn-sm removerFila">Remover</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Ahora necesitarás modificar tu método clonar en js para que gestione la posición en `values`, y podría ser algo así:

```
$('.clonar').click(function() {
  // Clona el .input-group
  var $clone = $('#formulario .row').last().clone();

  // Borra los valores de los inputs clonados
  $clone.find(':input').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is('date')) {
      this.value = {{ date('Y-m-d') }};
    } else {
      this.value = '';
    }

    // Cambiar a la siguiente posición del array de valores
    this.name = this.name.replace(/\[([\d]+)\]/, function (original, firstGroup)
        {
          return parseInt(firstGroup) + 1;
        }
    ));

  });

  // Agrega lo clonado al final del #formulario
  $clone.appendTo('#formulario');

  //Eliminar
  $(".removerFila").on("click", function(){ 
    $(this).closest(".row").remove(); });
})
```

Y para terminar en tu controlador solo tendrías que tener el siguiente código, eso sí, valida correctamente los datos introducidos para que no permita incluir valor dañinos, como por ejemplo ejecutables que puedan extraerte información...

```
public function store(StoreLubricantes $request){
    $values = $request->validated()['values'] ?? null
    if (is_null($values))
      // no han mandado nada que sea correcto... mira a ver que quieres hacer en este caso :D 
    }

    if (Lubricantes::insert($values)) {
      return redirect()->route('admin.lubricante.index');
    } else {
        // Fallo al insertar valores, loguea, depura y arregla lo necesario para que no ocurra y devuelve siempre un fallo al usuario este te lo agradecerá
    }
}
```

Esto es solo una de las aproximaciones... podrías no tocar nada del front y hacerlo todo en el controlador, si no vas a tener muchos usuarios, adelante, el performance no será un problema. Si la base de datos está bien dimensionada tampoco tiene porque ser tan importante realizar un único INSERT con todos los valores por lo que podrías hacer el bucle que tenías pero llamando al `create()` eso sí mira la documentación de laravel y define bien el modelo con sus guardeds y sus fillables para evitar problemas y fallos de sql ;D.

Intenté explicarme lo mejor posible, cualquier aporte será bienvenido.
Ten en cuenta que he modificado el código que has aportado directamente en el editor de stackoverflow, no lo he probado y como comenté es una propuesta. Es muy posible que tengas que ajustar alguna cosa pero creo que la idea se entiende perfectamente y que podría ayudarte.